# For what is TrafficStats good for?

Tags: android, android-volley

I invested some time study the volley implementation, and found this piece of code in Class NetworkDispatcher:

```
            // Tag the request (if API >= 14)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag(request.getTrafficStatsTag());
            }
```

What can be done with this ?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)?

Answer (score 2):

It tags the current thread, so that you get its traffic separated in DDMS's Network Statistics tab.